Is it constructive to ask for research effort when flagging as a dupe?
I've been finding myself closing a lot of beginner-style questions as duplicates lately. For many of them, my dupe-finding process is just two steps:

Paste the title into Google.
Click the first result.

When that happens, I usually edit the auto-comment to something along these lines:

This question is similar to: {question}. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. (PS: I found this by googling your title - some research effort is expected on Stack Overflow.)

Is that addendum constructive? Or should I just leave the comment alone?

No. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76195/332043

Flagging a question as a duplicate generates an appropriate comment. Your additional commentary does not really change the situation. I would not advise modifying the auto generated canned comment

Both your PS and 1.2. list come across as flawed. If you just google the title and that's it - that's often not sufficient to find actual duplicates. Most likely that is not what you intended to say, but it reads a lot like "look, google has a hit for those keywords! Must be a dupe!".

@MisterMiyagi In some (rare) cases, it really has been sufficient. This question is the most recent example.

@AndrewYim That's kind of my point. That "In some (rare) cases, it really has been sufficient" means in a lot of cases it's not sufficient.

@MisterMiyagi That's why I don't do it in cases when it's not sufficient.

It is presumptuous too. You recognise it as a duplicate. Chances are, the question author did not if they took the time to search. You can't make the assumption that not enough research effort was made, it is just as likely that it is a lack of understanding which is the source. A single stack overflow post is likely not going to resolve that.

You are not asking for research effort.
You are going out of your way to add a snide remark. It does not ask for any action. It can easily be misinterpreted. It detracts from the advice already given.
It is not constructive.

Some have suggested commenting "I found [this link] by searching for [term] on Google" on other Meta posts about RTFM-style comments. Could something along those lines, minus the link to "How much research is expected?", be more useful?

I'm thinking something along the lines of [canned comment] + "I found this dupe by searching [term]" so OP can see my research process.

@AndrewYim I am sceptical of any "Google this" advice. Search results are highly personalised. Especially if you are a subject matter expert, your results are likely skewed towards that technology whereas regular people would get quite different results.

@AndrewYim Also note that any "I did X" is not actionable advice. You are relying on people to go the extra mental mile from "someone did X" to "I should do X too". Don't do that. People are really bad at going the extra mental mile for you if you just shot them down.

Ooh, I forgot about personalization. That's a really good point.

@AndrewYim - Sharing your research process isn’t required when flagging as a duplicate

@SecurityHound Can it be constructive, particularly for new users? (Legitimate question, I’m semi-new here.)

@AndrewYim - I find the modification to the canned message to be slightly condescending to be honest, so I don’t find your modification to the message, to be helpful.

@SecurityHound Not this message in particular (it seems pretty much established that it's a bad idea), but showing your research process in general.

@AndrewYim - As a question author I wouldn’t care provided the duplicate answered my question. As an individual with the same question I also wouldn’t care provided the duplicate answered my question. As a community user I find the modification of the canned message to be condescending, so I probably would flag it as such, so in every role at least for me it wouldn’t be found to be helpful.

Your post seems to imply that duplicates are a bad thing when they're the result of a low-effort question. But that's not really true - duplicates can be helpful, particularly for beginner-level questions where people might not know what search terms they should be using. So even if you feel OP should have done more work in this particular instance, their question could help others in a similar position.
It's not your job to force people to do research. Besides, a comment like this is likely to come off as snarky, which won't be very helpful at all.
And if the question really is that bad, it'll get auto-deleted once it gets enough downvotes anyways.
